# Android Storage permission WRITE ONLY?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am really tired with debugging this problem. I have an application that writes to a storage. The application worked fine, until I got an update (I don't know which update caused it, because I had a break from Android development) - my Android version is 6.0.1 now.

Anyways I am trying to write to my external storage. I got prepared reading the new permission system for Android, got the permissions, and I am doing a check in my code:

```
checkSelfPermission("android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
checkSelfPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
```

By debugging I've checked (I also get a code that checks and asks if permission is necessary, but I wanted to be sure that it really is ;) ) I've observed that they return value 0, which is equal to **PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED**

So, the permissions are granted for sure. I am trying to create an App directory in the storage to write pdf files, store sqlite DB and stuff like that.

Here is how I create the directory:

```
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        // We can read and write the media
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String sNewDir = Constants.ApplicationDataDir;

        if (sSubDir == null) {
            sSubDir = "";
        } else {
            sSubDir = sSubDir.trim();
        }
        if (sSubDir.length() > 0) {
            sNewDir += File.separator + sSubDir;
        }
        File dirName = new File(dir, sNewDir);
        if (!dirName.exists()) {
            if (!dirName.mkdirs()) {
                LogDump.e("getAppDirectory err", " (sSubDir=<" + sSubDir + "> cannot create dir: " + dirName.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        return dirName;
    } else {
        // Something else is wrong
        LogDump.e("getAppDirectory err", " (sSubDir=<" + sSubDir + "> not mounted state: " + state);
        return null;
    }
```

The value of dirName is /storage/emulated/0/MY_APP_CONST_VALUE/sSubDir  (the sSubdir is a parameter for subdirectory ie. "Preferences")
Soo, the code (checking with debugger) the execution checks that the directory does not exist, and the mkdirs() returns false result. THAT actually means that the directory does not exist, and could not be created.

During my application operation my logs get filled with:

```
 W/FileUtils: Failed to chmod(/storage/emulated/0/MY_APP_CONST_VALUE/DB/pcdrdata.sqlite3): android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

from the SQLLite code
And FileNotFound exception for any other file operations...

This seems quite logical since It cannot create the directories, right?
Now for the most confusing part:

I am using total commander, and I can see that the directories are actually being created, the sqlite database is being copied, and all the files that do FileNotFoundException are there. I made a test, deleted them, rerun the App, and they are copied to the location once again. However any read operation on the files is not possible.

So it somehow creates the directories, allows to write (even thouh mkdirs() says otherwise) to them, but does not allow to read.

I am really confused, and tired of trying. I also tried the same without the SD card - identical results though.....

My application creates PDF files - they are created successful, but even the Total Commander says that it cannot open them....

My phone is Xperia Z3

Comment: Try a full uninstall and reinstall of your app (not just running a new version from your IDE).

Comment: FWIW, I put your code in a scrap application, with `targetSdkVersion` of 22 and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the manifest, and it worked fine on a Nexus 5X running Android 6.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

As of KitKat you can't read from the root of the external storage anymore.  You can only read in special public directories or in your own private directory on the sdcard.  If you're seeing them created but not able to alter them, it seems like Android decided you could write there but not read there

Comment: I also tried getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) and the result was the same.
So where should I store app data? I am 100% sure it worked fine on KitKat

Comment: [External storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). If you hold `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (including runtime permissions depending device and `targetSdkVersion`), you can read from the root of external storage (`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`) without issue.

Comment: @CommonsWare so why can I not read from it? I am holding the permission, and using getExternalStorageDirectory and it does not work.

I am also unable to open /storage/emulated/0 with Android Device Monitor which is weird

Comment: @maslan: "I am also unable to open /storage/emulated/0 with Android Device Monitor which is weird" -- so far, your symptoms feel like an issue with your device.

Comment: @CommonsWare might be, I was able to run this application without changing API level on my LG tablet....